# Looking for a geometrical proof

Tags: geometry

Initially, $FG$ and $IK$ are two perpendicular chords of the black circle (centered at $A(0, 0)$ and radius $= r$). They intersect at $E$ such that $FE = x$ and $EG = y$.

[image]

If $D$ is the midpoint of $FG$, then, then $FD = \frac {x + y}{2}$ and $DE = \frac {x – y}{2}$.

Letting $AE = d$, we have $d^2 = DE^2 + AD^2$

$= DE^2 + (r^2 – FD^2)$

$= r^2 – [FD^2 – DE^2]$

$= r^2 – [(\frac {x + y}{2})^2 - (\frac {x – y}{2})^2]$

Eventually, $d^2 = r^2 – xy$ ……. (1)

Now, use $D$ as center with $FD$ as radius to construct the red circle such that it cuts $IK$ at $H$. If we let $HE = t$, then $t^2 = xy$ by applying similar triangles.

Then, (1) becomes $d^2 + t^2 = r^2$ ………. (2)

To realize this relationship, I use $E$ as center and $EH$ as radius to construct the blue circle so that $EH$ is rotated a bit to $EL$ (still equals $t$); where $L$ is the intersection of the black and blue circle.

According to the converse of Pythagoras theorem, (2) implies $\angle AEL$ is a right angle.

Note that $A$ does not lie on the blue circle. It probably will also not on $FH$ too.

I have also uploaded the following simplified version (with minor details, even names, erased).

[image]

Assuming the above is correct, I want to raise the following questions:-

1. Can this result be proved (instead of the above) geometrically?
2. Can this result be of any significance in geometric application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\Gamma$ be the black circle. From Euclid's theorem we have:
$$\operatorname{pow}_{\Gamma}(E) = IE\cdot EK= FE\cdot EG = EH^2 = EL^2$$
but since $L\in\Gamma$, it follows that $LE\perp EA$ as wanted.

Honestly, I do not know if this result, holding in this particular configuration, may be useful in other circumstances.

Comment: That is great. It is the first time I learn that 'the power of a point' can be used to determine the midpoint of a chord.